# Center my navigation buttons

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot of solutions to center my navigation buttons but non worked and I don't find the right solution. I tried space-between but I want it responsive.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">The performances</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">About Us</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">Book Now !</a></li>


</ul>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;}

nav a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav .btn{
  -webkit-border-radius: 17;
  -moz-border-radius: 17;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #8B0000;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;}

.btn:hover{
  background: #A26161;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thank you for your advices !

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS contains a `nav`element, but the HTML doesn't. I added one, and also added `nav { text-align: center; }`:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 17px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #8B0000;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #A26161;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">The performances</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">About Us</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">Book Now !</a></li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution!

```css
nav{
  text-align: center;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;}

nav a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav .btn{
  -webkit-border-radius: 17;
  -moz-border-radius: 17;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #8B0000;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;}

.btn:hover{
  background: #A26161;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">The performances</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">About Us</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">Book Now !</a></li>


</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `nav` element surrounding the `ul`, add the following CSS style for `nav`:

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

It leaves you with the following:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav .btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 17;
  -moz-border-radius: 17;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #8B0000;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #A26161;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">The performances</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">About Us</a></li>

    <li class="btn"><a href="">Book Now !</a></li>


    </ul>
</nav>
```